# Analogue of Ubuntu's Disks in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, format

I just switched from Ubuntu to Xubuntu. I'm just trying to format a USB drive, but I don't find the Disks utility which I used on Ubuntu. Do I need to install something in Xubuntu in order to format my USB drive (what do you suggest?), or is there a tool that comes by default that I can use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use `gparted`. Install by opening a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and typing:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

If you would insist on using the disk utility:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility
```

Sorry for the short answer, but that's all. **;)**